# Do the symbols at the bottom of the loading screens mean anything?

Tags: bastion

I noticed that when I am on a loading screen, what looks like a feather scrolls across with some symbols underneath, like this:

[image: Bastion loading screen]

Do these symbols mean anything? Or are they just random pretty gibberish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to decipher from it, and [this interview of Jen Zee and Greg Kasavin](http://www.vis-atk.com/2011/10/12/the-kid-asks-about-a-typeface/) tends to confirm it:

> What we ended up doing as sort of a compromise was to assign meaning
>   to the uses of the alphabet where it appeared in the game. There are a
>   number of games with their own made-up alphabets whose character sets
>   all conveniently map to the 27-letter English alphabet and whose words
>   coincidentally map to English words. We didn’t want to use the
>   Caelondian alphabet as some kind of a code, so we settled for it
>   having no direct English analog.

If you want to give it a try anyway, it seems to be always the same sequence (or sub-parts of it) repeated, and horizontally flipped for the bottom line.

[image] ([larger pic](http://uppix.net/2/3/7/39eb038e2f357abe9a50b7f3dbbdc.jpg))

Check it out: I just flipped the second line horizontally and shifted it on the left.  Two sequences appear, and sequence B contains a sub-sequence of sequence A (sequence C).

I also added a list of what I think are the different glyphs that can be found in the sequences, if that can help to decipher.

Comment: According to that interview, the symbols are the Caleondian lyrics for the song ["Build That Wall"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8cELTdtw6U).